# Is there any way to monitor EBS IOPS/BurstBalance for AWS Elasticsearch Service nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

I can't seem to find any EBS metrics in CloudWatch for my AWS Elasticsearch nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Elasticsearch **does not provide** same metrics as for EBS volumes used in EC2 instances. The available metrics for EBS volumes used by ES [are](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-cloudwatchmetrics-master-ebs-metrics):

ReadLatency, WriteLatency, ReadThroughput, WriteThroughput, DiskQueueDepth, 
**ReadIOPS, WriteIOPS**